# TFS: Get the user's name of locked file

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, vcs-checkout

While trying to checkout a file \ folder in a Workspace, I get 0 as a result if the action was failed.
Usually it fails because someone else already checked it out with lock.

Welp, I would like to know who is this user (to bump his ass). How do I do that?

My code:

```
var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(folder);
var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri);
var workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(server);
int result = workspace.PendEdit(new[] { jsonFile }, RecursionType.Full, null, LockLevel.CheckOut);
if (result == 0)
{
    // How to get the user's name ?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection coll = YOURTEAMPROJECTCOLLECTION;

PendingSet[] pending = coll
        .GetService<VersionControlServer>()
        .QueryPendingSets(new[] { jsonFile  }, RecursionType.None, null, null);
```

'pending' will contain any pending changesets, who has it checked out, etc.

Comment: Thanks.
Had my wish at OwnerDisplayName in PendingSet :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2012 you get the name of the locker person in the Output window

Comment: I know. I want to get it by code so I'll be able to present it in my application

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [QueryPendingSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.querypendingsets.aspx) method!